# Perl to parse text file

Tags: perl, file, validation, parsing

here Im writing a perl program which to parse a file, it contians multiple line, in each line it has three fields: name, size in bytes and user.

any sample code to validates the file? for example, if I want to check if a given file through argument that it is validate file?

Comment: Posting the file, along with any code you have tried, may be a good place to start

Comment: [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by ESR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a CSV file use a CSV parser 
For eg.
http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html